# DJANGO - SQLITE3, Improperly configured error

Tags: python, django, sqlite

This is my code from settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'paper.db',
    }
}
```

This is the code from wsgi file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Paper.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But i still get the error below when i try to save an object in the database from the terminal:

```
 20 def complain(*args, **kwargs):
---> 21     raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
 22                                "Please supply the ENGINE value. Check "
 23                                "settings documentation for more details.")

ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

I just upgraded to the new OS X El Capitan, if it is relevant. I really do not know what is going on.

Comment: You mentioned the terminal, so your wsgi file is irrelevant. How did you start the Python shell?

Comment: i started the virtual environment and than i work with ipython. I initialized the model and when i press .save(), this error appears. :-) i worked before with another app and there was no problem but since the upgrade i get this problem @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 0):

You should always start the shell with `manage.py shell`, rather than starting IPython directly. That takes care of all the setup for you.